# bus error 10 or segmentation fault 11 when trying to use pointers to char* depending on encapsulation

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to use a basic char* and can manage to do it in main, but when try putting it in another function, and then calling that function in main, I'll sometimes get a bus error or segmentation fault, but I'm not sure why.

This code works the way I'd expect:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    cout << "enter name:" << endl;
    char *name[10];
    cin >> *name;
    cout << "hello: " << *name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
enter name:
alex
hello: alex
```

But when I do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sayhello(){
    cout << "enter name:" << endl;
    char *name[10];
    cin >> *name;
    cout << "hello: " << *name << endl;        
}

int main(void){
    sayhello();

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine and the output gets to asking for the name, but I receive a buss error: 10. The output is:

```
enter name:
alex
Bus error: 10
```

Another issue I have is when I seem to do a very similar task, but do the same thing explicitly in main and add another function, I instead get a Segmentation fault: 11. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sayhello(){
    cout << "enter name:" << endl;
    char *newname[10];
    cin >> *newname;
    cout << "hello: " << *newname << endl;        
}

void testprint(){
    cout << "this is a test" << endl;
}

int main(void){
    testprint();

    cout << "enter name:" << endl;
    char *name[10];
    cin >> *name;
    cout << "hello: " << *name << endl; 

    sayhello();

    return 0;
}
```

My output for this is:

```
this is a test
enter name:
alex
enter name:
Segmentation fault: 11
```

It doesn't make any sense to me and I'm not sure why I'd be getting two different errors.

Comment: You need to learn more about pointers. An uninitialized pointer doesn't point to a valid place.

Comment: All your programs are undefined due to the use of uninitialised pointers. The first one does what you expect only because of bad luck.

Comment: Different errors in the same code means undefined behaviour. So do an initialization of the pointers, see if you get any errors. (`char *name = new char[10];`)

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
char *name[10];
```

defines an an array of `10` `char*` objects that haven't been initialized. Perhaps, you meant to use:

```
char name[10]; // An array of 10 chars.
cin >> name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pointer to char is confusing for beginner. I would advise the following:

```
void sayhello(){
    cout << "enter name:" << endl;
    char name[10];
    cin >> name;
    cout << "hello: " << name << endl;        
}
```

As said by Yu Hao, you have to learn more about pointer first.